# rvest returns empty list when trying to scrape a table from website

Tags: html, database, web-scraping, rvest, empty-list

I am trying to scrape tables from this website and rvest returns empty list. It works for other websites. what can be the issue?

Thanks,

```
library(rvest)
urlONGov <- "https://www.ontario.ca/page/2019-novel-coronavirus"
ONGov <- urlONGov %>%
  xml2::read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="pagebody"]/table[1]') %>%
  html_table()
ONGov
```

Comment: It looks like the page needs java.script. JS elements cant be loaded directly by using read_html and rvest. You could try a workaround by using RSelenium: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html or https://thatdatatho.com/2019/01/22/tutorial-web-scraping-rselenium/. If this is just a oneshot-extraction id stick with the webdriver version (link 2), if you want to use it more frequently id set up the docker (link 1)

Comment: Thanks. I'd seen RSelenuim, but when I want to install and load the package I get this error: > library(RSelenium)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RSelenium’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘caTools’    can't find this caTools and I have updated my R/Rstudio. and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

The table is dynamically retrieved from an API call you can find in dev tools network tab when refreshing the webpage. The call returns json which you need to traverse to retrieve some html you can then parse the table out of.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(rvest)

table <- jsonlite::read_json('https://api.ontario.ca/api/drupal/page%2F2019-novel-coronavirus?fields=nid,field_body_beta,body')%>%
     .$body%>%.$und%>%.[[1]]%>%.$safe_value%>%
      read_html()%>%html_node('table')%>%html_table()
```